# Java .equals() returning false when the strings are equal

Tags: java, android, string, equals

I'm making a an application and I want the application to automatically log in from a text file if the user has already logged in. Currently, in the text file i have "alex|ppp" which matches the database entry.
The following method is called first

```
private void rememberedLogIn(){
    String filename = "UserInfo.txt";
    String info = "";
    String user = "";
    String pass = "";

    try{
        FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput(filename);
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
        info = r.readLine();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }

        for(int i =0; i < info.length();i++){
            if(info.charAt(i) == '|' ){
                user = info.substring(0,i);
                pass = info.substring(i+1);
                GlobalVar.loggedIn= true;
                break;
            }
        }
        new InitialStuff().execute(user,pass);
}
```

I have double checked the values for user and pass and they are "alex" and "ppp" which is expected. Next InitialStuff is called, this is the relevant code:

```
public class InitialStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Toon>{
    int prog = 0;
    @Override
    protected Toon doInBackground(String... params) {
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
        Toon toon = null;
        Database db = new Database();
        db.establishConnection();
        if(db.tryLogIn(params[0], params[1])){
            prog = 2;
            publishProgress();
            toon = db.getToonFromDB(params[0]);
            prog = 4;
        }else prog = 3;
        publishProgress();
        return toon;
    }}
```

The problem occurs once i call the db.tryLogin() which looks like this

```
public boolean tryLogIn(String toonName, String toonPass){
    try{
        while(!connected) establishConnection();
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT Password FROM Toons WHERE Name LIKE '" + toonName+"';";
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rSet = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
        if(rSet.next()){
            String dbPass = rSet.getString(1).trim();
            if(dbPass.equals(toonPass)) //PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
                return true;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){ }
    return false;
}
```

I have checked to see that dbPass comes back from the database as "ppp" which matches toonPass yet it will skip over the return true and return false instead.

If it helps, this is the information eclipse gives me about the two

toonPass    "ppp" (id=830041185816) 
    count   3
    hashCode    0
    offset  5
    value   (id=830041185744)
        [0] a
        [1] l
        [2] e
        [3] x
        [4] |
        [5] p
        [6] p
        [7] p

dbPass  "ppp" (id=830041708816) 
    count   3
    hashCode    0
    offset  0
    value   (id=830041709136)
        [0] p
        [1] p
        [2] p

Pleaes note that i have also tried passing in "ppp" to the tryLogin() method without taking it as a substring in case that had something to do with the problem and the outcome is the same.

EDIT: I solved the problem...sorta. I just stopped using the .equals() method and instead am using a for loop that compares the characters in each string to one another

Comment: Unrelated, but sql injection.

Comment: This is the first time i've dealt with external databases in my programming and I had to teach it to myself so please excuse my lack of knowledge...what do you mean?

Comment: One of SQL-injection examples: http://xkcd.com/327/ -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: @user3293629 consider what happens if `toonName` is `"foo' or '1' = '1"`

Comment: @fge i don't understand what you're trying to say :/

Comment: @user3293629 expand the string by yourself and see what your query becomes...

Comment: Heh. Nice comic Pshemo. A safer approach than embedded SQL is a parameterized stored procedure.

Comment: I'm quite amused why you got 0 for `hashCode` of both `toonPass` and `dbPass`, since I got 111216. On unrelated notes, some tips for you: 1) Don't forget to `close()` the `FileInputStream fIn` and `BufferedReader r` after you have done with them. 2) The `for-loop and if-block` for finding the pipe "|" character can be changed to `indexOf("|")`. 3) Don't forget to remove `waitForDebugger()` when it's not used. 4) As already mentioned before, be careful with SQL injection. 5) Don't forget to close the connection to DB too if it's currently not used.

Answer (score 2):

one **hint!** 
if you're playing with String class methods  eg. .compare() .equals() etc. **remember about charset encoding!** especially ensure to match with IDE, project files ,resources & db's encoding (when you load/read data as string from external sources)

Comment: equals String and Charsequence always return **false**. Good hint :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(dbPass.equals(toonPass)) //PROBLEM OCCURS HERE
```

Are you really sure ?

The problem is probably here:

```
catch(Exception e){ }
```

Write this instead and inspect your logs:

```
catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: I added that in but as i expected it didn't change the result, there is no exception being thrown it simply skips over the if statement directly to the "return false"

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, it looks like the Eclipse debugging information isn't matching.  The `char[]` that you've printed out for `toonPass` looks like it reads "alex|ppp" and `dbPass` looks like "ppp".  The offset of 5 for `toonPass` makes it seem like the strings are equal because it's skipped the first 5 characters ("alex|") and is thus up to "ppp".

I'd suggest rewriting the loop that splits up the "alex|ppp" from the text file.  If you just want to split it on the '|' character then `info.split("|")` will probably do the trick.

Comment: Also, while it might not necessarily be the issue, I'd strongly recommend you follow the advice of @ben75 and avoid writing `catch(Exception e){ }`

Comment: i thought that might be the problem too but it isnt ("Pleaes note that i have also tried passing in "ppp" to the tryLogin() method without taking it as a substring in case that had something to do with the problem and the outcome is the same.") even when "ppp" is passed in as a new string it doesnt work.

Comment: I saw that at the end of your question, but it doesn't explain what we're seeing with the offset=5 in the debugging information.  Only other thing I can think of is a character encoding issue but with such simple characters it's highly unlikely.

Comment: would it help if i posted the info of the variables when i pass in "ppp"?

Comment: It can't do any harm to post that information, I suppose.  Frankly, though, if passing arguments of `info.split("|")[0]` and `info.split("|")[1]` doesn't work then I'm out of ideas for now!

Comment: @ATG when using `substring()` the resulting string share the same array of chars as the original one for speed ([it uses this constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.%3Cinit%3E%28int%2Cint%2Cchar[]%29)) but `equals` should work anyway.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that because `InitialStuff` is an `AsyncTask` it gets a different class loader and this is interfering with the equality of "ppp" loaded from the database compared with "ppp" passed in as an argument.  I didn't think this affected Strings, though, to be honest.

Comment: @ATG so what can I do to fix this?
Also, i should mention that when i use the tryLogin() method on strings pulled from a textbox it also works (and the strings are also passed in to an AsyncTask from a different method)

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest having a look at the differences in how the Strings are constructed between this code and the code that uses the text box.  I don't know the answer, I'm afraid.  It's all trial and error from here.